# How do I reuse a created member throughout an MDX statement?

Tags: mdx

I have a bunch of calculated members that I need to create which are referenced off a single date.

Rather than repeating the MDX that gets the date member for which the measure will be based off, is there a way to create the date member at the start, and then reference it throughout so that I don't have to repeat the MDX multiple times? I was thinking something like the below however it returns a NULL:

```
  WITH MEMBER [Date].[Retail].[Closing Date] AS
IIF (
  [Date].[Retail].CurrentMember.Level.Name = 'Date',
  [Date].[Retail].CurrentMember.PrevMember,
  [Date].[Retail].CurrentMember
)
MEMBER [Measures].[Closing New] AS
(
  [Date].[Retail].[Closing Date],
  [Measures].[On Hand Quantity]
)
SELECT
  [Date].[Retail].[Date].Members ON ROWS,
  {
    [Measures].[On Hand Quantity],
    [Measures].[Closing New]
  } ON COLUMNS
FROM
  Retail
WHERE
  [Date].[Retail Year].&[2017]
```

As above, I want to use the `Closing Date` member multiple times for various calculations.

Comment: uhmm just call the member you defined first everywhere you need it. You aren't trying to use [Closing Date] more than once on your example. Having any trouble/errors?

Answer (score 0):

To investigate why it is returning null try something like the following to see if it is as you expect:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[nm] AS
  [Date].[Retail].CurrentMember.Level.Name
SELECT
  {
    [Measures].[On Hand Quantity],
    [Measures].[nm]
  } ON 0,
  [Date].[Retail].[Date].Members ON 1
FROM Retail
WHERE [Date].[Retail Year].&[2017];
```

(I also switched the declaration order inside the SELECT clause as it is standard to declare columns, as it is axis 0, first followed by rows)

Answer (score 0):

Why yes, there is!

the pattern I follow here is to create a set of one member then reference the first item of that set.

```
with set currentDate as
[Date].[Retail].[Date].&[20160725]
```

then reference it in the remainder of your query as

```
currentDate.item(0)
```

Comment: Thanks David. Would this have any performance benefits? My gut says it would because it doesn't need to calculate the date for all other measures?

Comment: Using this pattern has several advantages.  The two main ones are
1. you can set a date in one place in your query and use the member everywhere else.  
2. it's a real member, so existing aggregations will be used (possibly resulting in performance gains)
2a. again, it's part of an existing hierarchy, so you can use functions like prevmember, parent, child, etc...